# Unescape Double Curly Braces on C#

Tags: c#, json, escaping

I have some json data stored in a database but, for any weird reason, it is stored with escaped curly braces, example:

```
{{"Id":10,"Title":"Account Data","Date":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","Data":{{"Id":22,"Name":"My Object"}}}}
```

What I want is to parse this string and obtain a valid json string, without statically replacing `{{` and `}}` by `{` and `}`, so I would have this:

```
{
  "Id": 10,
  "Title": "Account Data",
  "Date": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "Data": {
    "Id": 22,
    "Name": "My Object"
  }
}
```

I tried using Newtonsoft.Json for that, but I could not find a proper way to unescape it.

Some extra information:

- The data is stored in a column in an Azure SQL Database
- Modifying the way the data is stored is not an option

Does anyone know a good way?

Comment: data = data.Replace( "{{", "{" ).Replace( "}}", "}" );

Comment: it's not valid json. You probably have to parse it left to right while checking if you're in a string literal and then replace symbols

Comment: Yes, definitely check if you're in a string literal.

Comment: Why do you not want to statically replace {{ with { if it will get you the correct output?

Comment: If you don't want to do a `string.Replace()` as others suggest, you may need to implement your own version of [`JsonTextReader.cs`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.cs) that handles the double braces.

Comment: To use two string.Replace concatenated just to remove this seems a little hacky... But if there is no better, standard way to do that, then I will go with this solution. To write an entire `JsonTextReader` just for that is definitely overkill

Comment: It seems like overkill until 5 years from now, someone stores a double curly brace in a JSON value and your hack blows up. Maybe you'll luck out and it will never happen. Maybe you won't. In my experience, the aggregate chance of ugly hacks coming back to bite you grows to the point of certainty. I always address foreseeable issues from the outset.

Answer (score 0):

I have only idea how to do that: to format string replacing "{{" to "{" and "}}" to "}"

```
var str = "{{\"Id\":10,\"Title\":\"Account Data\",\"Date\":\"0001 - 01 - 01T00: 00:00.000Z\",\"Data\":{{\"Id\":22,\"Name\":\"My Object\"}}}}";
        str = str.Replace("{{", "{").Replace("}}", "}");
```

Comment: To use two string.Replace concatenated just to remove this seems a little hacky... But if there is no better, standard way to do that, then I will go with this solution. To write an entire `JsonTextReader` just for that is definitely overkill